# Cisco 1811w switch config

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan

Can someone help explain how to configure vlan routing on a 1811w? I have been banging my head over this for days. Currently I have fa0 on wan and fa1 on lan, with dhcp for the internal. I want fa1 on the second wan, but for now I just want the switch to work. I've created vlan10 and assigned fa2-5 to it. I gave the vlan an ip address 192.168.2.1/24. Now I'm lost as to how I would get that to route over to fa0. My understanding is I don't need trunking since the switch is integrated. Can anyone post some sample configs or anything? This device doesn't use the normal fa0/0 style, it's simply fa0-fa9.

Comment: I recommend posting your configurations along with a topology.  Better questions result in better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question confuses me a little bit.
If you only work on a 1811w you don't need trunking, just because trunking connects multiple routers or L3 switches. But I think you are only working with 1 here.

Can you paste your configuration here so I can have a better look?